# Having difficulty pasting values only from {copy(destination).range.end.offset}

Tags: copy, paste

I have tried every combination of paste special and can't figure this one out. I just want to copy the entire row's values, then paste them onto the next sheet. I am extremely close to being finished here, but a few of the cells I loop through have formulas that produce the values and I keep ending up with the lovely "REF" text in my cells.

```
Dim bottomL As Integer
bottomL = Sheets("Final Body Assembly List").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim c As Range
For Each c In Sheets("Final Body Assembly List").Range("B1:B" & bottomL)
    If c.Value >= 1 Then
        c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Summary").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

        End If
Next c

End Sub
```